# Python script "KeyError: "filename 'xxxxx.tar.gz' not found"

Tags: python, python-3.x, backup

I'm working on a Python backup script that archives the source directory to a compressed tar file then (to verify the backup,) extracts it to /tmp and compares (checksums of) the extracted files to their counterparts in the source directory. During the backup portion, if the directory to be backed up is specified on the command line, everything works properly. If not, the script asks if the user wants to backup the current directory. If I answer yes, I end up with this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/me/scripts/dir1/../backup.py", line 89, in <module info =
> tar.getmember(os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory)) File
> "/usr/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 1813, in getmember raise
> KeyError("filename %r not found" % name) KeyError: "filename
> 'Jupiter-home-me-scripts-dir1-230209-2014.tar.gz' not found"

This is the backup portion of the script:

```
import os
import sys
import datetime
import socket
import time
import tarfile
import shutil
import hashlib
import fnmatch

debug = 1
CURRENT_TIME = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y%m%d-%H%M")

HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
LOGFILE = "BACKUP" + "-" + HOSTNAME + "-" + CURRENT_TIME + ".log"
CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()

def log_message(message, logfile=LOGFILE):
    with open(logfile, "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{message}\n")

def debug_message(message):
    if debug == 1:
        print(f"DEBUG: {message}")

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()

log_message("Backup started at " + str(CURRENT_TIME))
debug_message("Backup started at " + str(CURRENT_TIME))

# sys.exit()

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    # directory to backup was not specified on the command line
    confirm = input("No directory specified. Backup current directory '" + CURRENT_DIRECTORY + "'? (y/n) ")
    if confirm != 'y':
        sys.exit()
    else:
        # user chose to use the current directory
        debug_message("1011: user chose to backup current directory " + str(CURRENT_DIRECTORY))
        directory = CURRENT_DIRECTORY
else:
    # directory to backup was specified on the command line
    directory = sys.argv[1]

if os.path.isabs(directory):
    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        debug_message("1013: " + str(directory) + " is a full path and exists.")
        backup_directory = directory
    else:
        debug_message("1014: " + str(directory) + " is a full path but does not exist.")
        sys.exit()
else:
# Check if the directory exists as a subdirectory of the current path
    full_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), directory)
    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
        debug_message("1015: " + str(directory) + " exists as a subdirectory of the current path at " + str(full_path))
        backup_directory = full_path
    else:
        debug_message("1016: " + str(directory) + " does not exist as a subdirectory of the current directory")
        sys.exit()

debug_message("1020: backup_directory = " + str(backup_directory))
log_message("Backup directory = " + str(backup_directory))

if not os.listdir(backup_directory):
    debug_message("1030: Error: backup directory ({backup_directory}) is empty")
    sys.exit()

backup_source = backup_directory.replace("/", "-")
HOSTNAME = socket.gethostname()
backup_file = HOSTNAME + backup_source + "-" + CURRENT_TIME + ".tar.gz"

debug_message("1040: backup_directory = " + str(backup_directory))
debug_message("1050: backup_file = " + str(backup_file))

with tarfile.open(backup_file, "w:gz") as tar:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(backup_directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            tar.add(file_path, arcname=os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory), recursive=False)
            info = tar.getmember(os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory))
            info.uid = os.stat(file_path).st_uid
            info.gid = os.stat(file_path).st_gid
            info.mode = os.stat(file_path).st_mode
    tar.close()

shutil.copystat(backup_directory, backup_file)

print("Backup created: ", CURRENT_DIRECTORY + "/" + backup_file)
```

I'm obviously missing something but it looks to me like there should be no difference whether the user specifies the directory or simply confirms to use the current directory. Either way, it passes the `backup_directory` variable to the rest of the script.

*Debug output - backup directory passed on the command line:*

```
DEBUG: Backup started at 230209-2013 
DEBUG: 1015: dir1 exists as a subdirectory of the current path at /home/me/scripts/dir1 
DEBUG: 1020: backup_directory = /home/me/scripts/dir1 
DEBUG: 1040: backup_directory = /home/me/scripts/dir1 
DEBUG: 1050: backup_file = Jupiter-home-me-scripts-dir1-230209-2013.tar.gz 
Backup created: 
/home/me/scripts/Jupiter-home-me-scripts-dir1-230209-2013.tar.gz
```

*Debug output - backup directory **not** passed on the command line, user chooses to backup the current directory:*

```
DEBUG: Backup started at 230209-2117
No directory specified. Backup current directory '/home/me/scripts'? (y/n) y
DEBUG: 1011: user chose to backup current directory /home/me/scripts
DEBUG: 1013: /home/me/scripts is a full path and exists.
DEBUG: 1020: backup_directory = /home/me/scripts
DEBUG: 1040: backup_directory = /home/me/scripts
DEBUG: 1050: backup_file = Jupiter-home-me-scripts-230209-2117.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/scripts/backup.py", line 89, in <module>
    info = tar.getmember(os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tarfile.py", line 1813, in getmember
    raise KeyError("filename %r not found" % name)
KeyError: "filename 'Jupiter-home-me-scripts-230209-2117.tar.gz' not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reproduce and debug your issue. And you are right, there is no difference whether current directory is used or not. It can be reproduced both ways.

The troublesome code is this:

```
with tarfile.open(backup_file, "w:gz") as tar:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(backup_directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            tar.add(file_path, arcname=os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory), recursive=False)
            info = tar.getmember(os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory))
            info.uid = os.stat(file_path).st_uid
            info.gid = os.stat(file_path).st_gid
            info.mode = os.stat(file_path).st_mode
    tar.close()
```

In case you are backing up the directory in which the tar.gz archive is being created then you end up trying to add the archive into the archive itself

```
tar.add(file_path, arcname=os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory), recursive=False)
```

However, there seems to be a fail safe mechanism and the file is not added.
By the way, you can check what is currently in the archive with

```
tar.getmembers()
```

On the next line you are trying to get info for the file, but since it was not added into the archive you get KeyError

```
info = tar.getmember(os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory))
```

There are multiple ways you can go about fixing it. For example you can put it inside try catch block

```
with tarfile.open(backup_file, "w:gz") as tar:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(backup_directory):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            tar.add(file_path, arcname=os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory), recursive=False)
            try:
                info = tar.getmember(os.path.relpath(file_path, backup_directory))
            except KeyError:
                # Log the error or do something else
            info.uid = os.stat(file_path).st_uid
            info.gid = os.stat(file_path).st_gid
            info.mode = os.stat(file_path).st_mode
    tar.close()
```